# Is there a way to protect the files inside a folder from making changes in Android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

In my Android application I am opening the documents like `ppt`,`excel` or `word` by using the native or installed applications. But when I click on edit it's accepting the changes and saving it.

Since these are all third party applications I cannot control these attributes, but is there any way to protect my files from these applications? I want these applications to open it but shouldn't allow to make any changes in it.

The files are in `sd-card` `folder`. I am using `Eclipse`, `Java` for my development.

Comment: What about creating an hash key and save this some where, and if this key is changed show the file as corrupted. Not a solution just a random thought

Comment: move the files to the apps /data/data directory, or at least a copy of them.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is from my conclusion

The Read and write permission which have all capabilities trying avoiding write permission in your manifest and check, or your third party doesn't have rights to write to any document.